# How to scrape network activity and responses with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When we open Google Chrome's inspect element, and go to the Network tab (instead of the default element tab) we can monitor the requests that are sent by our browser and the contents. When I go to *this particular link* (I can't share the link), I receive these `json` responses (as illustrated) and this tab records the responses real time. Now, there are hundreds of links, I don't want to click on every link just to record the network activity and the `json` responses.  I know `selenium` is a web browser API, and I know `bs4` is for web scraping. The question is, **how to automatically record the request links that are sent and the `json` responds (as the picture illustrates) using python?** 
[image]

Comment: Share the URL for which you want to scrap the data.